# How do I hide expand icon in ui-grid tree view?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I dynamically look up children but in certain cases I do know if a row is a leaf node or not. 
In these cases I'd like to hide the + icon for that particular row.

Lets say the

```
row.entity.status == 'leaf'
```

decides whether we need to hide the + icon.

The API attribute  "showTreeExpandNoChildren" completely removes the icon for all nodes that are yet to be loaded.

Is there any other way to localise this bahavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to make your own implementation of ui-grid/treeBaseRowHeaderButtons template and replace binding to showTreeExpandNoChildren to asking to your row.entity.status